# Looking for a way to do force caching kivy widgets

Tags: python, kivy

I am currently making an embedded multi-touch software using Kivy.
However, our hardware spec is little tight, so I am trying to optimize GUI for better performance.

Then I've found that Kivy Popup is slow when first pops up then gets faster after that. So now I am guessing that Kivy is doing some caching.

So, I want widgets, especially popups and screens since they are very slow, to act like they were opened once before.

I've tried to open and dismiss every popup widgets and go through all the screens when initializing the program. It seems quite effective except that I could not figure out how to hide the screen changing yet, but I am looking for some better approach.

I've looked for kivy document about kivy.cache [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.cache.html)

But it is not clear whether this is what I am looking for or not. In addition, it is hard to understand what do I have to do and what to expect as a result. (Seems it does not work in a way that I want anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be best to find what takes most time during the first startup, to make sure to cache that, instead of preloading every possible widget. One possibility is that it's just loading the default style texture, which you can load by setting the source of any image widget to `images/defaulttheme-0.png`, the first widget that needs it (that includes popup) will not to load it itself if you do. If you find that even after displaying a Button, the first Popup is still slow to load, then that's certainly something else, maybe running kivy at `trace` log_level will help seeing what happens last before the slowdown.

`python -c kivy:log_level:trace main.py`

Comment: Is there anyway I can manually cache particular widgets such as popups and screens before starting the program?